# Acessing data inside a Matplotlib GUI callback function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python, and somewhat new to object oriented programming.  Can anyone explain what is going on and how things are typically done with a matplotlib GUI callback?  I've taken the "event_handling example code" from the Matplotlib website and stripped it down for clarity.  When you run this code it makes a plot, and if you press a key on the keyboard the **press** function is called.  The **press** function is passed only event, but somehow every other variable from main program level appears inside the call to **press** but as a global variable, is this normal for functions?  I can print the value of x, but if I try to change it then it makes a local variable version, worse yet now I have seemingly no way to access the global version anymore?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.random.rand(3)
y=np.random.rand(3)

def press(event):
    print(x)    
    print('Local Var:', locals().keys())
    print('Global Var:', globals().keys())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I have searched and had quite a hard time finding any reference that explains how to access or properly pass useful data in and out of the callback function so that a GUI event can do something useful, like update some data or feature of a plot?

So lets say I wanted to have the callback function modify y and re-plot the data.  How is that typically done?

Answer (score 0):

you have global access to `x` inside your `callback`, but can't modify it unless you specify it `global`.

```
def press(event):
    global x
    ...
```

`locals().keys()` and `globals().keys()` are printing `namespaces`; I am unsure why you need to do that.

Your `callback` receives an `event` that you can use and manipulate inside the function.

### **Here is an example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.random.rand(3)
y=np.random.rand(3)

def press(event):
    print(event, event.key)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)

ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

click on the plot window to set the focus.
```

pressing f should print the event object and set the plot full screen
pressing f again, will print f and restore the size of the window
pressing s will print s and will offer to save your figure
etc...

To learn more about how you can manipulate `events`, look up `backend_bases` in the very rich `matplotlib` web site. For example, you can set mouse_clicks events that allow you to capture canvas coordinates to add points or modify figures...

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify:  The only reason I printed the namespaces is to illustrate that it seems odd to me that local variables from the main program can be assessed inside the callback function as global variables?  I'm using the "key_press_event" example because it's simple.  There are many GUI objects,  like the lasso ect..  I get info about the GUI event passed into the callback function, but how do i use that info to do something useful like modify the data inside the callback function.  Is my only option to really use globals inside the callback function?  That does not seem right?

Comment: You can use classes & OOP to segregate your namespaces. Other than that, the way you structured your example makes it difficult to avoid it.